# After repositioning an image above another, its previous area can still be clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I find it difficult to describe this problem without example, so I reproduced it in JSFiddle: [JSFiddle_Example](https://jsfiddle.net/nu6csuzp/1/)

Full Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen, print" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" media="screen, print" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .plus { position: relative; right: 27px; }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <i class="fa fa-archive fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-lg fa-inverse plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title">
              MyModal
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Not only is the area of the plus sign, in the example above, still able to be pressed to bring up the modal, it also highlights. What can be done to remedy this?

Update: I would like to have the plus icon to still be clickable along with the full icon, so not to confuse the user. (The modal is intended to expand the image)

Update 2: To be more specific of the issue here is a screenshot of the highlighting/click-area error: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql9R7.png)

The extra area that the highlight is extending to is the original position/area of the plus icon. That area, in addition to being highlighted, can still be interacted with. I would like it so that small area would go away but still have the plus icon clickable.

Comment: @c-ommen Hey I found a hacked way of achieving what you are looking for 
.plus { position: absolute; left:45px; top:48px }

Comment: Okay, yeah that works. Thank you! Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Yes the a tag spans the length of the original placement of the elements. When you set position:relative the flow of the DOM still remained so the a tag was still as long as it initially was but when you set position absolute it doesn't follow the typical DOM flow so it shrinks the a tag down to the right size. Not sure if It said it correctly but that is how I understand it.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Would you like to post that as an answer so I can close the question? Or would you prefer I post it and reference you?

Comment: You can answer and reference me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so @Orlando P. figured out a fix. Here's a JSFiddle link for example:
[JSFiddle_Example](https://jsfiddle.net/11cnygxq/)

Relevant Change:

```
.plus { position: absolute; left:46px; top:48px }
```

And as for the explanation, I will quote Orlando P. directly:
"[The] a tag spans the length of the original placement of the elements. When you set position:relative the flow of the DOM still remained so the a tag was still as long as it initially was but when you set position absolute it doesn't follow the typical DOM flow so it shrinks the a tag down to the right size."

Answer (score 0):

If you want the plus sing to be on top and not to trigger the modal it needs to be outside the link tag. As long as it is inside the link tag it is will trigger the modal.

Correct me if I'm wrong about what the expected behaivor is.

Try: https://jsfiddle.net/nu6csuzp/2/

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      <i class="fa fa-archive fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      
    </a>
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-lg fa-inverse plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title">
            MyModal
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the suggestion, I just updated my question. I do want the plus to be clickable as not to confuse the user. The intention is to have the image the plus icon overlays to expand in the modal. Plus after taking a look at your changes, the still is a slight jaggedness to the selection box. I wonder if there is a way to correct that. If so that would completely fix my issue.

Comment: Hey, I am still a little bit confused about what the expected behavior is and what is it that you want to fix.

So far I understand that you want the plus sign to be clickable along with the box, to trigger the modal, a feature that is working with your current code.

So what is the issue? If you can describe it and maybe add screen shots I think I'll be able to help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Alex, I added a link to a screenshot and hopefully a better description of what I'm looking for. Thank you for your patience!